# jQuery(document).ready(function(){ isn't waiting for Background Image to load first before Fadein

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, background-image, fadein

I'm having trouble with `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` - my issue is that it's not waiting for the background image to load first before fading in when I clear the cache. So what happens is there's a delay before the wrapper fades in then the image is visibly scaling down the screen as it loads.

I'm building with Headway Themes on Wordpress.

It's making me go insane :)

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.background-image {
  background: url('http://www.aliceandowl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Purity-London-Homepage-Banner.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.background-image.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  jQuery(document).load(function() {
  jQuery('.background-image').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('visible');
  });
});
```

I have tailored this from: http://codepen.io/graygilmore/pen/hxpEt

Any solutions are beyond appreciated!

Thanks,
Danielle

**I have just made the site live (it's VERY much under construction ha) - you'll see the background image on load:
http://www.aliceandowl.com
Thanks guys!**

**So far all answers given are doing the same thing, and the issue still remains that the Fadein doesn't wait for the Background Image to load first.**

Comment: Have you tried `$('.background-image').load() { });`?

Comment: No luck @D4V1D but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! I took a break and came back to it which usually helps, I came across the following which now works perfectly, thank you for all your help guys!

CSS:

```
.background-image {
  background: url('http://www.aliceandowl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Purity-London-Homepage-Banner.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 

    display: none;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://www.aliceandowl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Purity-London-Homepage-Banner.jpg').load(function() {  
      jQuery('.background-image').fadeIn(2000);
    });
  });
```

Now I'm going to have the biggest glass of wine ;)

Answer (score 6):

`$(document).ready` doesn't wait for resources to load. It just makes sure that the callback is called after *DOM is loaded*.

For resources, use `$(window).load`, which triggers the callback function only when external resources like js/css/images are loaded.

> The `load` event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead of `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Code here
});
```

Comment: Does the page still run successfully?

Comment: Yes, it runs exactly how it did previously - I'm sure I must be going wrong somewhere just can't figure it out! Thanks Zak

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: `.load();`

This waits until all images, flash... load: `$(document).load(function(){});`

This, however, never waits for your images to load, it is waiting only until basic HTML is loaded:
`$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
try relacing this with all your `jQuery(document).load(function() { ...`:

```
var image = 'http://graygilmore.com/images/bk-body.jpg',
        img = $('<img />');

img.bind('load', function() {
     $('.background-image').addClass('visible');
});

img.attr('src', image);
$('.background-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
```

commentout

```
//background: url('http://graygilmore.com/images/bk-body.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```